# Qual é a diferença entre workflow_dispatch e repository_dispatch no github actions?

Tags: github

Eu quero criar uma action que vai disparar um evento (`repository_dispatch` ou `workflow_dispatch`) em um certo repositório A, e em outro repositório B vai ter uma action que vai ser executada quando esse evento for disparado, executando um script neste outro repositório B. Quero saber qual seria mais adequado, o `repository_dispatch` ou `workflow_dispatch`? E qual é a diferença entre eles?

Comment: Olá, Lucas! Por favor, você pode explicar por que quer fazer esse encadeamento?

Comment: Já descobri a resposta... (eu acho)
Eu quero executar um workflow no readme.md do meu profile sempre que eu abrir uma issue em alguns repositórios meus. Esse workflow vai ser responsável por atualizar o readme do meu perfil, rodando um script no node.js (build do readme) que busca informações nessas issues com o octokit/graphql. Nesse caso vou de workflow_dispatch, pq pelo que entendi ele só dispara um workflow específico, enquanto o repository_dispatch pode disparar todos os workflows de um repositório. E nesse eu vou ter que disparar "manualmente" (script) pela API REST o workflow_dispatch.

Comment: Blz, entendi como você pretende resolver o problema... Mas o que você está tentando colocar no ReadMe? E por que? Se você puder compartilhar, só para eu entender o problema que você está tentando resolver

Comment: Eu quero reservar um espaço no readme do meu perfil para exibir coisas que eu tenho aprendido e estou aprendendo ultimamente, mas não quero ter que ficar editando toda vez que eu for começar a estudar algo novo. Essas informações (coisas que ando estudando) já ficam nos repositórios que eu crio pra ir estudando, então quero usar o github actions pra automatizar esse processo de edição do readme do meu perfil. É algo parecido com isso: https://simonwillison.net/2020/Jul/10/self-updating-profile-readme/ porém, trocando o cron jobs por workflow_dispatch e outras fontes de dados...

Comment: OK, entendido... E interessante! Compartilha o seu usuário do Github pra eu te seguir, e quem sabe contribuir com essa ideia. O meu é egomesbrandao.

E se você chegou na solução, responda a sua própria pergunta aqui... é legal para outros usuários terem essa visibilidade.

Comment: Meu username é lucas-lm. Logo mais vou elaborar melhor uma resposta e posto aqui!

Answer (score 2):

A diferença entre o *workflow_dispatch* e o *repository_dispatch* é que o *workflow_dispatch* aciona apenas um determinado workflow, enquanto o *repository_dispatch* pode acionar todas as actions associadas à um repositório. Ambos são *triggers* manuais e podem ser disparados via API REST do github ou diretamente da UI do GitHub Actions.

No meu caso de uso, onde eu queria atualizar automaticamente o readme do meu perfil com informações do meu repositório de estudos, a escolha mais adequada é adicionar um *workflow* que vai ser acionado pelo *workflow_dispatch*, pois esse é o único *workflow* que será executado nesse repositório.

### Mas como eu faço a atualização automática do readme?

Sempre que eu começo a aprender algo novo, eu começo abrindo uma **issue** no meu repositório de estudos. O título dessa **issue** é o assunto que comecei a estudar. Dessa forma, o que eu queria fazer era adicionar esse assunto (que é o título da **issue**) em uma lista (lista de coisas que estou aprendendo) que tem no readme do meu perfil. Eu automatizei esse processo com 2 **workflows**, sendo 1 no repositório do readme do meu perfil e outro no meu repositório de estudos.

#### Workflow do readme do perfil

O workflow do readme do meu perfil é acionado via *workflow_dispatch*, e sempre que ele é acionado ele segue os seguintes passos:

1. [Checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) - Ação padrão do GitHub para iniciar o workflow
2. Buscar dados pela API do github com [github-script](https://github.com/actions/github-script) (títulos das minhas issues abertas no meu repositório de estudos)
3. Salvar os dados buscados da API em um arquivo (data.json)
4. Instalar o node.js com [setup-node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node)
5. Executar comandos de build (`yarn` e `yarn build`)
6. Adicionar o novo `readme.md` ao github (`git add`, `git commit`, `git push`)

#### O comando build

O comando `yarn build` executa a CLI do [mustache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache) com os dados de `data.json` e o template `readme.mustache` para gerar o novo readme.

#### Workflow do repositório de estudos

Esse **workflow** é responsável por acionar o **workflow** do repositório do `readme` do meu perfil sempre que um novo **issue** for aberto. Já existe uma action criada pelo [Ben Coleman](https://github.com/benc-uk) que faz isso, então é só usar ela (https://github.com/benc-uk/workflow-dispatch).

#### Código

Os repositórios que eu apliquei esses workflows são abertos e todo o código está disponível no github:

- [Repo do meu perfil](https://github.com/lucas-lm/lucas-lm)
- [Meu repo de estudos](https://github.com/lucas-lm/nowiknow)